# Param with more values

Tags: powershell, parameters

Early days with CMD and Batch I use the [`shift`](https://ss64.com/nt/shift.html) command.

How I do that with PowerShell?
Here my sample:

```
# test.ps1
# start ps script with parameters
param(
    [string]$varmon)

if ($varmon) {
    foreach ($var in $varmon) {
        Write-Host $var
    }
}
```

> PS CLI: .\test.ps1 one two three

I get only "one". How can I start the script with more parameters than one?

Comment: set $varmon to be an array like this `param([string[]]$varmon)` or if you are expecting any kind of object use `[object[]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [the automatic variable `$args`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-6#args):

```
# test.ps1
# start ps script with parameters
foreach ($var in $args){
    write-host $var
}
```

Arrays allow you to enter a variable number of arguments - at the end of the day `$args` is just an automatic array that's created for unassigned variables.

Array parameters are **comma** delimited, not space - example below.

**test.ps1**

```
# test.ps1
# start ps script with parameters
param(
    [int[]]$numbers,
    [string[]]$names
)

if($numbers){
    Write-host "`nYou have entered the following numbers:"
    foreach ($num in $numbers){
        write-host "Number     : $num"
        Write-host "Square root: $([system.math]::sqrt($num))"
    }
}

if($names){
    Write-host "`nYou have entered the following names:"    
    foreach($name in $names){
        Write-host $name
    }
}
```

---

**Example 1:** Without using the parameter names, you will need to keep the arrays in order. So `$numbers` first, and `$names` second

> PS CLI: .\test.ps1 4,9,16 john,jim,jane

---

**Example 1:** With parameter names, you can change the order.

> PS CLI: .\test.ps1 -names john,jim,jane -numbers 4,9,16

Comment: When i use $args, i get back "two" and "three". But not "one". Why?

The UseCase is simple. Less work, when i tart the script one Time. Otherwise i repeat ".\...".

Comment: remove the `param($varmon)` part otherwise one is assigned to the variable `$varmon`. You may want to consider arrays if it's the same type of "thing"?

Comment: Thanks. Without "param" it works. 
What is the use, to handle with a array? For example this script:

# start ps script with parameters

foreach ($var in $args){
    [system.math]::sqrt($var)
}

PS-CLI:  .\test.ps1 9 16 25 49

What can i do better, when i take a array?